# Photoshop like color blend with CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am trying to blend 2 gradients to achieve a photoshop like background blend affect.
http://jsfiddle.net/fmgfsr4o/2/

I tried playing around with  `background-blend-mode: multiply;` but I am not able to achieve the desired affect.
Basically, the overlapping area in the above fiddle needs to be blended.

Is that even possible with css?

P.S. I am not too certain about the blend mode and haven't used it at all in the past!

Here is the image for the desired affect -

---

[image]

Comment: Before posting a question like this, I would check out what type of blend modes are possible in CSS, and how widely supported they are. They are fairly new

Comment: @AndyHolmes http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Comment: @Kshitiz show us image as the effect appears in psd

Comment: @C-linkNepal yeah i know, that's the point i'm making

Comment: I have edited the question and attached the image for the desired affect. One issue which I think I narrowed it down to is that I need to be able to blend backgrounds of 2 elements. From what I understood after poking through the CSS Blend modes, you can blend images and colors on the same element only?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `mix-blend-mode`: Here's your code with that property set to `multiply`: http://jsbin.com/nodide/2/edit

The `background-blend-mode` only mixes the colors of your background images and any background color, while `mix-blend-mode` takes care of the blending of overlayed elements.

It is slightly less supported than `background-blend-mode` at the moment: it works in latest Firefox & Safari, and in Chrome and Opera if you enable the experimental web platform stuff.